# Query over selenium automation

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am doing automation but unable to click on a hyperlink by using findElement(). Sharing that part of the inspect elment of the code . Can anyone help ?

```
<div class="nametag" data-request-type="immigration">

    </div>
    <div class="name">

    </div>
    <div class="info">
        Click <a href="" ng-click="openNewRequest(currentUserInfo.personId, 2)">
            here</a> to submit new visa request.
```

Comment: Can you share the section of your automation code for this as well? With what has been provided we can give suggestions on what you can use to click on that link, but can't identify why what you're currently using isn't working, which would be useful to help you avoid similar scenarios in the future.

Comment: @Anita Pandey : Have you tried using `linkText` or `partialLinkText` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using css selector. Here's the full code.

```
By linkLocator = By.cssSelector("[data-request-type="immigration"] .info a");
driver.findElement(linkLocator).click();
```

Comment: can you give the whole function ? like how to proceed

Comment: sharing the function with you :


  final WebElement visa=driver.findElement(By.id("pageContainer"));
  //final WebElement img=visa.findElement(By.className("ng-scope"));
 
  final WebElement tab=visa.findElement(By.cssSelector("section[id=^self]"));

Answer (score 0):

Considering your element code, you can use linktext to click on hyperlink. Use the below generic function to click. Following code is in c#:

```
click(By.LinkText("here"));


    public void click(By by) //method starts from here
    {
    try
    {
        WebDriverwait wait; 
    wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)).click();

    }
    catch(WebDriverException er)
    {

    }

    }
```

Comment: I need the java version of it . Thanks

Comment: Not a big difference.                                                click(By.linkText("here");

public void click(By by)
     {
         try
         {            
         WebDriverWait wait;
  wait=new WebDriverWait(d,20);
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)).click();
          
              
         }
         catch(WebDriverException er)
         {
          
         }
     }

Comment: thanks @rajkumar ..can you help in switching to new window ? once i open the new hyperlink it should open in new window of the same browser

Comment: @AnitaPandey Selenium can switch to a new window after clicking on a link using the window name as well as handles. what have you already tried? I suggest that you start a new thread to discuss this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".info a"));
    String href = e.getAttribute("href");
    driver.get(href); or driver.navigate().to(href);
```

Comment: thanks @HeziIsraeli . Can you help me in switching to new window ?

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(handle). You can take do getWindowHandle() to get current handle and after the all handles from driver.getWindowHandles().

Comment: @HeziIsraeli navigating using value of `href` might not work because `href` attribute is empty in the shared html.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait before click. you can use below xpath for click on hyperlink.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = 'here']"));
```

For how to use explicit wait please go to below link.
https://trickyautomationworld.blogspot.in/2018/02/implicit-wait-vs-explicit-wait-vs.html